# Organizing channels on OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Assuming we have R, G, and B created images:

```
IplImage *R=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *G=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
IplImage *B=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

and we are having an image A like:

```
IplImage *A=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
```

When we split A into 3 channels, the order has to be:

```
cvSplit(A, R, G, B, NULL);
```

or

```
cvSplit(A, B, G, R, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCV's default channel order is **BGR**